# map an array with index keys to return a list of items react JS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, list, arraylist

I have an array here that I would like to map out and list in radio check boxes.

I currently can only get one item of the array to return by typing out for example: `<IonLabel>{item[1]}</IonLabel>`

How would I get all of them to list out?

**'equipment' Array**

```
{0: "Camera", 1: "Wide Angle Lens (16mm equivalent)", 2: "Tripod", 3: "Drone"}

0: "Camera"
1: "Wide Angle Lens (16mm equivalent)"
2: "Tripod"
3: "Drone"
```

**Current Code**

```
{equipment.map((item, i) => {
          return (
        <IonItem key={i}>
         <IonLabel>{item}</IonLabel>
         <IonRadio slot="start" value="biff"/>
        </IonItem>

          );
        })}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using not an Array, but an Object with numbers as keys.

Try this one:

```
{
  Object.values(equipment).map((item, i) => (
     <IonItem key={i}>
       <IonLabel>{item}</IonLabel>
       <IonRadio slot="start" value="biff"/>
     </IonItem>
   )
  );
}
```

Another solution could be in rewriting your `equipment` to look like:

`const equipment = ["Camera", "Wide Angle Lens (16mm equivalent)", "Tripod", "Drone"]`
In this case, you could use your previous implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is not an array, but an object.

You can store the data in an array like this:

```
['Camera', 'Wide Angle Lens (16mm equivalent)', 'Tripod', 'Drone']
```

Now you can iterate over it using map just like you have done in your example.